# Python H2O histogram error: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, h2o

I am learning Machine Learning using H2O. I have a small Table with names, address and age, and I tried to create a histogram by age. 
I am using iPython with Python 3.

Age column is:

```
24
23
22
23
23
22
25
```

Output with plot=Fase is:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th style="text-align: right;">  breaks</th><th style="text-align: right;">  counts</th><th style="text-align: right;">  mids_true</th><th style="text-align: right;">   mids</th><th style="text-align: right;">   density</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">   22.75</td><td style="text-align: right;">     nan</td><td style="text-align: right;">      nan  </td><td style="text-align: right;">nan    </td><td style="text-align: right;">nan       </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">   23.5 </td><td style="text-align: right;">       2</td><td style="text-align: right;">       11  </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 23.125</td><td style="text-align: right;">  0.380952</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">   24.25</td><td style="text-align: right;">       3</td><td style="text-align: right;">       11.5</td><td style="text-align: right;"> 23.875</td><td style="text-align: right;">  0.571429</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">   25   </td><td style="text-align: right;">       2</td><td style="text-align: right;">       12  </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 24.625</td><td style="text-align: right;">  0.380952</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

[image]

Comment: If you can produce a [mcve] and the error in text form (no image), you can create an issue at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: in additional to a reproducible code snippet (examples here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/x.html#example) please see the docs on histograms: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight=hist#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.hist

Comment: Sorry if my comment above wasn't clear. This is a bug due to a combination of H2O and matplotlib. It should be reported on the matplotlib issue tracker to check why it occurs from one version to the next, without deprecation period and to be able to fix this. @Lauren  Since bugs are rarely documented (;-)), reading the docs doesn't help. You can avoid running into this bug by using matplotlib 2.2.3 or lower.

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! and yes sorry I didn't realize the second link you provided was to the matplotlib github issues. I'll wait on a code snippet to see if I can reproduce the issue with a given version of H2O-3 and matplotlib.It'd be good to know how the versions match up.

Comment: @Lauren I think this is pretty straight: The current development version of H2O will work with matplotlib version <= 2.2.3 and fail with matplotlib 3.0.0.

Comment: Well, actually the `left` argument is already deprecated since matplotlib 2.2.2 and the warning said explicitely that it will be removed in 3.0. So there is no point in filing a bug report; it will not be reverted. This means a bug report at h2o makes more sense (there is no bug tracker though..not sure how to best report it?)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest bugs for H2O-3 can be tracked here: http://jira.h2o.ai.  If you could file that would be awesome, but if you'd prefer not to I will look into this a bit later and file a bug if it makes sense (still need sometime to review the whole issue, so have really appreciated your help so far)

Comment: @Lauren Mhh, I don't find a way to log into that issue tracker. So just to summarize it here: The [`pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) signature is `bar(x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None,..)`, which means you need to change [Line 2538](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/a98c32139ba27a0a1ccd7b8e4766db07789ced0a/h2o-py/h2o/frame.py#L2538) of the source code to `plt.bar(lefts, counts, width=widths, bottom=0)`. This would be backwards compatible down to at least matplotlib 1.5 (probably even lower).

Comment: You might also consider explicitely setting `align`, if you need to support very old matplotlib versions.

Comment: Thank you ImportanceOfBeingErnest and Lauren. I will continue my training with older versions for now. Please tell if you need anything from me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and Petru Tanas the issue is being tracked here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5969 (thanks for the help and reporting the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is a compatibility issue between H2O-3 and the newer versions of Matplotlib. The issue is being tracked [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5969) and the current workaround is to make sure you are using an older version of Matplotlib like version 2.2.3 or lower.